# Determining existing local windows accounts via .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, interop, com-interop

In a C# application I use the following code to **determine existing local windows accounts** (inkl. filtering build-in security principals for some reasons):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Account Where LocalAccount = True AND Status = 'OK' AND (SidType = 1 OR SidType = 5)" + 
                 " AND (SID <> 'S-1-3-3' AND SID <> 'S-1-3-2' AND SID <> 'S-1-5-9' " + 
                 "      AND SID <> 'S-1-5-8' AND SID <> 'S-1-5-10' AND SID <> 'S-1-5-12' " + 
                 "      AND SID <> 'S-1-2-0')");
ManagementObjectCollection objects = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementBaseObject obj in objects)
{
    ....
}
```

Now I am looking for an **alternative method/way** to determine existing local windows accounts like above because this method is not very stable --> sometimes an **COMException** is thrown ( when executing searcher.Get() ):

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x800706BA) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at
>   System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()

The exception occurs non-determinstic in my opinion.

Comment: What is the message/content of the COMException?

Answer (score 2):

I do not exactly understand what u need but here is a good example of getting all windows accounts on the system

http://csharptuning.blogspot.com/2007/09/how-to-get-list-of-windows-user-in-c.html

and to get current system user u simply write

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

you can also do something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username : {0}", envVar["Name"]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a context (including a "machine" context for the local accounts), and then easily find users and/or groups:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

// find all users - define a "UserPrincipal" as your "QBE" principal
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// enumerate all users
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

foreach(Principal p in searcher.FindAll())
{
    // do something here
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD: